# Remove pictures as attachments inside an email

Tags: email, attachment, salesforce-for-outlook

I would like to know when an email is moved from the app "Salesforce for Outlook" to Salesforce, is there a way to remove pictures as attachments inside that email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000g5DMAAY) which has been delivered in Winter 15 - specifically focusing on filtering attachments. I'm not sure if you are referring to filtering out attachments or simply removing them all together from original emails when they are moved into Salesforce. Alternatively, there is a [setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_personal_config_email.htm&language=en) which you can use to not save attachments at all.

This is discussed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hMoJAAU) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

To be more specific, I would like to remove pictures of an email signature which are stocked as attachments.

But I understand that it is not possible, I can remove all attachments or no one but not filter.

Comment: Your understand is correct. If my response earlier was the information you were looking for, please mark it as as the answer so that it benefits others.